# Why isnt my PWA not showing the updated page version?

Tags: angular, google-chrome, progressive-web-apps

I created an Angular website. I recently accessed it on my phone using the chrome app. By clicking **Add to Home screen** I created a very simple PWA (Yes I am aware that this isn't the proper way of creating a PWA). I noticed that after making changes to the app, the changes reflect on my desktop Chrome browser, but NOT on my phone regardless if I fire it up via the app icon or via the browser. It is paramount that I get it working on both phone and desktop browser.

Can some kindly explain why this is happening and how I can fix this?

Find below my Angular environment:

[image]

Looking forward to your help!

Comment: Are you publishing your changes before accessing on your mobile?

Comment: @shaktimaan I publish first,  then try to access the page on phone and  desktop. And it makes no difference how many times I try refreshing on my phone...

Comment: According to [this][1] your desktop and mobile should be requesting ngsw.json. Can you check your network requests to confirm whether this is happening.


  [1]: https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-devops#update-checks

Comment: Also maybe you can check for updates and log/confirm to make sure your app is indeed getting updated. https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-communications#checking-for-updates

Comment: Does your PWA when running with an HTTPS URL pass as a valid PWA with the Chrome Lighthouse tool?

Comment: What changes are you making?